# Is there a way to add a blank option with VS Code snippets placeholder choices?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am trying to create a snippet that gives me choices for optional attributes. I have used this approach in the past where I just put a blank space as a `choice` in the `placeholder`. That works when there is only one option between other parts of the snippet but like in the following example if I wanted to skip both placeholders (optional attributes on the adorn) there would be multiple spaces in the generated code which I would have to delete manually.

```
"Adorn": 
  "prefix": ["adorn"],
  "body": [
    "<%= adorn${1| , color: :blue, color: :white|}${2| , inline: true|} do |a| %>",
      "\t$0",
        "\t<%= a.adornment %>",
          "\t\t",
        "\t<% end %>",
    "<% end %>"
  ],
  "description": "An adorn"
},
```

From what I can see [in the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar) it doesn't seem possible to do what I want using `placeholders` and `choices`. I thought I could use a variable and just have it resolve to empty string but the grammar doesn't seem to allow for that.

Is there any other way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: As a note, there is an [open issue on the VS code repo to handle this situation.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34368)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some unicode characters in snippets, so I tried backspace (did not work) but `\u200B` which is a **"zero-width space"** does.  So you can do this in your choices:

`{1|\u200B, color: :blue, color: :white|}${2|\u200B, inline: true|}`

and if you choose the blanks (i.e., the `\u200B`'s) a zero-width space will be inserted.  And you get what you want - no spaces to be deleted.

But I leave it to you to see if there are any parsing or other problems with having that character in your code.  Maybe it is or isn't a problem in your language.  See the open issue (which I found after posting this answer initially) https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34368 ("Allow "empty" as a choice in snippets
") where the zero-width space option is warned against and may cause problems - so test it.  It doesn't look like there is any other option but a regular space which you have tried.

I tried "null" `\u0000` and it wasn't recognized by vscode.

Comment: Although this is not exactly what I would have hoped for, it certainly is a creative workaround I had not considered. Thank you for including the link to the open issue confirming the behavior is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

if a blank space is all you need, then all is needed is an '$1' that the placeholder.

but first let's see if you have errthing

## First

at the root of yow project you need a new dir call .vscode

[image]

in side yow dir add a new file **NOTE** name is very important yow new file's must have this pattern `any`.**`code-snippets`**

in side yow new file add this

```json
{
    // Place your global snippets here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a scope, prefix, body and
    // description. Add comma separated ids of the languages where the snippet is applicable in the scope field. If scope
    // is left empty or omitted, the snippet gets applied to all languages. The prefix is what is
    // used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
    // $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders.
    // Placeholders with the same ids are connected.
    // Example:
     "Print to console": {
        "scope": "javascript,typescript",
        "prefix": "log",
        "body": [
            "console.log('$1');",
            "$2"
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
     }
}
```

To finish I recommend you to remove the scope attribute. and do not use the file for more than one language, bcuz if you do so it may not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get an empty value for a placeholder with choices is to add a choice of 1 character and remove this with Delete or Backspace (depending where the cursor is, it differs for the 2 placeholders) and then TAB to the next placeholder.

To get the choice list for placeholder 2 press TAB when you are at placeholder 2.

Watch the location of the separating spaces, they are at the end of the choice.

```
  "Adorn": {
    "prefix": ["adorn"],
    "body": [
      "<%= adorn ${1|e,color: :blue ,color: :white |}${2|e,inline: true |}do |a| %>",
        "\t$0",
          "\t<%= a.adornment %>",
            "\t\t",
          "\t<% end %>",
      "<% end %>"
    ],
    "description": "An adorn"
  }
```